# dynamodbクエリでINを使用する方法はありますか？

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

使用クライアント: https://github.com/guregu/dynamo

このテーブルから、Key1を指定、Key2を複数指定したもので取得したい為、IN句を使用して値を取得する方法はありますか？

| key1(HASH KEY) | key2 (SORT KEY) | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | val1 |
| A | 2 | val2 |
| B | 1 | val3 |

SQLであれば、以下のイメージになります。

```sql
select key1, key2, val1 from test where key1='A'and key2 in(1, 2)
```

クライアントは資料を読む限り、プレースホルダーに、任意の値を指定する機能しかありません。
HashKeyだけを指定して、取得後にフィルターしてもいいのですが、
可能であれば取得時に除外したいため、IN句の使用を検討しています。

クライアントとして書きたいイメージとしては、配列などからIN句に値が指定したいだけなので、以下のようなイメージになります。

```golang
arr = []int{1,2}
table := DB.Table("test")
err = table.Get("key1", "A").Filter("'key2' IN (?)", arr).All(&results)
```

この場合、エラーにはなりませんが、値も取得できません。
※GetとRangeでHashKeyとSortKeyを指定した場合、値の取得はできます。

例えば、以下の様に文字列として条件を指定した場合も、値を取得することはできません。おそらく2重にクォート処理されているのでしょう。

```golang
table := DB.Table("test")
err = table.Get("key1", "A").Filter("'key2' IN (?)", "'1','2'").All(&results)
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html

IN句を使用してデータを取得できるかどうかの確認のため、CLIでも確認しました。

```bash
aws --endpoint=http://localstack:4566 dynamodb query \
--table-name test \
--key-condition-expression 'key1= :key1' \
--filter-expression 'key2 in (:key2)' \
--expression-attribute-values '{ ":key1": { "S": "A" }, ":key2": { "N": "1" } }'
```

この場合、1件のデータが取得できます。

```bash
aws --endpoint=http://localstack:4566 dynamodb query \
--table-name test \
--key-condition-expression 'key1= :key1' \
--filter-expression 'key2 in (:key2, :key3)' \
--expression-attribute-values '{ ":key1": { "S": "A" }, ":key2": { "N": "1" },":key3": { "N": "2" } }'
```

key2の条件を以下のようにすると、特に値を展開する機能がないのか、値が取得できません。

```bash
'{"key2": {"L":[{"N": "1"}, {"N": "2"}] }}'
```

この場合も、文字列として扱われるためか、値が取得できません。

```bash
'{"key2": {"S":"'1','2'"}}'
```

複数の任意の値をフィルターのIN条件に追加するためにはどのような方法がありますか？

Comment: 「正常に動作しません」とのことですが、では実際にはどのように動作しましたか？　質問者さんの手元で起こっている問題を正確に把握するためにも、想定していた挙動と実際の挙動が分かるように質問文を [edit] いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: たとえば、`key2` が primary key になっているのではないかなと思っています。

Comment: いえ、Key1がhash keyで　key2が sort keyのテーブルになります。
知りたいのは、QueryFilter を使用した場合のIN句の指定方法になります。

Comment: なるほど、つまり composite primary key ですね。そういった事情を把握するためにも、まずは状況をより詳しく解説するための情報を [edit] して追記いただけますか。回答者が状況を再現できる程度に詳しいとありがたいです。何かしらの理由によって質問者さんの手元と回答者の手元では挙動が変わることがあるので、質問者さんの手元で実際にどのように動いたのかの情報があると嬉しいのです。

Comment: composite primary keyであるかどうかは、あまり関係ないという認識だったので記載していませんでした。
QueryFilterを使用する場合、Hash＋Sortでも、Hashのみの場合でも、その条件で取得された後、サービス側でフィルタ指定が実行されるため、Indexがあるかどうかは影響がないという記載を見た記憶があります。

Answer (score 2):

質問文の状況下では、`in` 演算子を使わずに BatchGetItem を使う方がオススメです。順番に説明します。

### プライマリーキーには `in` 演算子を使えない

まず、プライマリーキーに対しては [FilterExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression) を利用することができません。これは[複合プライマリーキー (composite primary key)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey) の場合も同じです。今回の例だと `key2` はソートキーであるため、FilterExpression で使うことができません。

また、KeyConditionExpression で使える演算子は[限られており](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions)、特に `in` 演算子を利用することができません。

したがって、`key2` に対して直接 `in` 演算子を使うことはできません。もし使おうとすると `Filter Expression can only contain non-primary key attributes` というエラーが出ます。

```bash
% aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name test \
    --key-condition-expression 'key1 = :v1' \
    --filter-expression 'key2 in (:v2, :v3)' \
    --expression-attribute-values '{":v1": {"S": "A"}, ":v2": {"N": "1"}, ":v3": {"N": "2"}}'

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Filter Expression can only contain non-primary key attributes: Primary key attribute: key2
```

（※この部分の挙動が質問者さんの環境での挙動と異なるため、もしかすると質問者さんのお手元の DynamoDB テーブルは何かしら説明と設定が食い違っているか、LocalStack を利用されているようなので挙動差があるのかもしれません。）

### セカンダリインデックスを使う方法

抜け道として、[セカンダリインデックス](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html)を使う方法があります。つまり、複合プライマリーキーを構成するパーティションキーとソートキー（別名：ハッシュ属性と範囲属性）のうちパーティションキーのみをプライマリキーとするセカンダリインデックスを作ってクエリ時にそちらを使うようにすれば、FilterExpression で `key2` が利用できるようになります。

たとえば質問文のテーブル `test` に対して `key1-only-index` という名前で `key` のみをプライマリキーとするセカンダリインデックスを作ってクエリした例が以下です。

```bash
% aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name test \
    --index-name key1-only-index \
    --key-condition-expression 'key1 = :v1' \
    --filter-expression 'key2 in (:v2, :v3)' \
    --expression-attribute-values '{":v1": {"S": "A"}, ":v2": {"N": "1"}, ":v3": {"N": "2"}}'                                                             
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "val": {
                "S": "val2"
            },
            "key1": {
                "S": "A"
            },
            "key2": {
                "N": "2"
            }
        },
        {
            "val": {
                "S": "val1"
            },
            "key1": {
                "S": "A"
            },
            "key2": {
                "N": "1"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Count": 2,
    "ScannedCount": 2,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

ただし、FilterExpression では **フィルターが適用される前のデータに対して** 1 MB のデータサイズ上限があります: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions

> A `Query` operation can retrieve a maximum of 1 MB of data. This limit applies before the filter expression is evaluated.

もともとソートキーであった `key2` をソートキーとして利用せずにフィルターしているため、DynamoDB 内でのデータ処理に無駄が生じる場合が多そうです。このときデータ量制限に引っかかる可能性も普段よりかは高くなっているでしょう。

### BatchGetItem を使う方法

ここまでの事情により、`key2` の候補の数が少ないのであれば、`in` 演算子を使うのではなく [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) を使う方がオススメです。つまり、複数のソートキーをひとつずつ指定するやり方です。BatchGetItem であればソートキーをきちんとソートキーとして利用できるため、テーブルの設計を上手くできていれば計算効率も高くなるでしょう。

具体的な実行例は以下です。

```bash
% aws dynamodb batch-get-item --request-items '{"test": {"Keys": [{"key1": {"S": "A"}, "key2": {"N": "1"}}, {"key1": {"S": "A"}, "key2": {"N": "2"}}]}}'
{
    "Responses": {
        "test": [
            {
                "val": {
                    "S": "val1"
                },
                "key1": {
                    "S": "A"
                },
                "key2": {
                    "N": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "val": {
                    "S": "val2"
                },
                "key1": {
                    "S": "A"
                },
                "key2": {
                    "N": "2"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "UnprocessedKeys": {}
}
```

今回クライアントとして利用されている https://github.com/guregu/dynamo にも https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/guregu/dynamo#Batch.Get という形で BatchGetItem の実装があるので、これを利用できそうです。

Comment: 細かくありがとうございます。

Comment: 細かくありがとうございます。

BatchGetで要件は満たせそうです。
実環境の方で同一のクエリを実行すると、おっしゃる通りエラーが発生しました。
Localstackとの差異の様です。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

key2がソートキーなのでFilterが使えません。

> フィルタ式には、パーティションキーまたはソートキーの属性を含めることはできません。フィルタ式ではなく、キー条件式でこれらの属性を指定する必要があります。[[ソース]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression)

BatchGetItemで取得できます。

```golang
err := table.Batch("key1", "key2").
    Get(dynamo.Keys{"A", 1}, dynamo.Keys{"A", 2}).
    All(&results)
```

Comment: なるほど。ありがとうございます。